# GeoExt Popup always loading after first click

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, geoext, popup

I'm trying to put popups on my map to show the feature's info. I have done that, however after the first click the mouse pointer starts loading and never stops.

```
var control = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
              url: "/geoserver/prod/wms",
              layers: [restaurantes,ruas,linhas_agua]
});


control.events.on({
        getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
        if (popup)  { popup.destroy(); }
        popup = new GeoExt.Popup({
        title: "Informação",
        map: mapPanel,
        layers: [restaurantes,ruas,linhas_agua],
        width: 250,
        autoScroll: true,
        collapsible: true,
        bodyStyle: {padding: 5},
        html: event.text,
        });
        popup.show();
        }

});

mapPanel.map.addControl(control);   
control.activate();
```

Comment: Do you get a valid response of your GeoServer instance? Can you check this (and maybe share the response) by your browser's developer tools?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).